# how to get only active calls from PhoneStateListener

Tags: android

I would like to get only active calls from PhoneStateListener.
I have created the listener with method   onCallStateChanged.
Once I dial (and the call is picked up) the state is already off-hook.

Well, it doesn't really surprise me, because of the text in the [API](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK):
Device call state: Off-hook. At least one call exists that is dialing, active, or on hold, and no calls are ringing or waiting.

But is there a possibility to get only active calls?

Answer (score -1):

From what I tried on my nexus one, active call wake CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK,
try use log file to watch the steps.

Try this ..

```
private PhoneStateListener mPhoneListener = new PhoneStateListener() {
public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
        switch (state) {
        case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
                Log.d(TAG, "ringing goes here");
                break;

        case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK:
                Log.d(TAG, "Active call goes here");
                break;
                
        case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:
                                Log.d(TAG, "CALL STATE IDLE goes here");
                break;
         default:
                Log.d(TAG, "Unknown state=" + state);
        }
}
```

and then call it :

```
 @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    
        TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager)getSystemService(TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
        tm.listen(mPhoneListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
}
```

Don't forget add permission to your Mainifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
```